# HTML Form Submit To Self

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

Can someone tell me why on earth this is not submitting to self?

I have the following setup:

```
<?php
     print_r($_POST);
?>

 <form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action"" >
    <table id="loginTable">
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="loginUsername" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="loginPassword" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

and every time I click on the submit button i see nothing inside the POST array. What simple thing have I totally overlooked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from the fact the equals is missing from your `action` attribute in your form element.

Your inputs need name attributes:

```
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 <form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action"" >
```

should be

```
 <form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action="" >
```

Missing = sign.

You're also missing the name attribute inside your input tags, so change

```
<input type="text" id="loginUsername" />
```

and

```
<input type="password" id="loginPassword" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" />
```

and

```
<input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" />
```

Comment: :-) html needs a compiler maybe ?

Comment: Error or it's not submitting ?

Comment: ah, doensn't like the capital "S" in submit but that also doesn't seem to get the POST array seeing the data.

Comment: see the suggestions below about adding a name attribute to everything. I missed that actually. No "name" attribute, no data will go through.

Comment: @sjobe: He's missing the name attribute. See Richard's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

- You should add **equals** sign between *action* and ""
- Also specify **name** attribute for each input field.

---

```
<?php
     print_r($_POST);
?>

 <form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action="" >
    <table id="loginTable">
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="login" id="loginUsername" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="loginPassword" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="Submit" value="Login" /></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
      print_r($_POST);
?>

<form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
  <table id="loginTable">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="loginUsername" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="loginPassword" /></td></tr>
  </table>
  <input type="Submit" name="submit_button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Save the file with .php extension

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["submitted"])){
    print_r($_POST["values"]);
} else {
?>
 <form name="bizLoginForm" method="post" action="?submitted" >
    <table id="loginTable">
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="values[]" id="loginUsername" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="values[]" id="loginPassword" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```